# Hiding status bar in iOS 7 when using PhoneGap Build 3?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I've been searching and reading about this all day, but no one specific post was made about how to disable it when you are using PhoneGap Build - using the newest version 3.1.0
I've found many answer on how to make it work if you build it yourself, but my problem is getting build.phonegap.com to build it correctly.

I set

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

in the config.xml and that used to work for version 2.9.0
The major change moving from 2.9.0 to 3.1.0 seems to be the exclusion of plugins. I figured something happened to the statusbar and so it seems. I tried to add the statusbar plugin like this:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
```

But that didn't help. I also tried adding javascript code to remove it programatically like this:

```
if (window.plugins && window.plugins.statusBar)
    window.plugins.statusBar.hide();
```

The if was added so i can run the scripts on my desktop where the phonegap.js is not loaded (it is automaticly provided by the build service)

I also tried fooling around with this option

```
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-translucent" />
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.

Nothing seems to change the behavior of the statusbar. Does anyone have a solution or perhaps just offer some help/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on my Phonegap Build App [Bd v3.4.0]:

In config.xml :

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" /> 
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
```

On device ready function:

```
 StatusBar.hide();
```

Reference: https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin

Comment: Yes. I don't know why it didn't work for me previously, but it works now.

Comment: This worked great to hide it. Is there a way to prevent the overlap?

Answer (score 0):

Have you mention in plist Status bar is Initially hidden Yes
and 
in app delegate didfinishlaunchingwithoption you have to mention below code regarding this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
```

{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
}

and write below methods too in app delegate

`- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
    {
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    }

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
        return YES;
    }`

Comment: Your answer does not seem to relate to my question. I'm using PhoneGap *build* (as stated in my question) and can only use javascript and xml configuration